# What are the health differences between pollen and honey?

Tags: benefits, nutrition, pollen, honey

I am wondering if there are any health differences between eating [pollen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollen) and honey. Or does the body treat both substances equally?

To put it bluntly, is one healthier than the other?

Comment: What do you mean by health differences? Do you mean nutritional value?  Then absolutely.  Gram for gram, there are ~4.3X the amount of calories in honey, which should be obvious as from it's sugar content.

Comment: Apologies for my imprecise wording. I am not a health expert. Basically I was just wondering whether one is healthier than the other.